# Block in custom module not registering on a particular site

Tags: 7, blocks

I'm having issues with a block that is created with a module I wrote. This module works on 2 out of 3 sites, all of which have a similar setup, so I'm not sure why it's being picky on one site.  Here is what I know:

1. The block is not showing up in the list on admin/structure/blocks, and is not available anywhere else.
2. hook_block_info() is being invoked on the site, but none of the other functions are being called. On the other two sites, calls are made to all the functions.
3. There aren't any blocks in the `blocks` table with the same name, but there is a record of the block in the table for each active theme.
4. I tried deleting these records out of the `blocks` table with no luck.
5. I've tried clearing cache and uninstalling/reinstalling with no luck.

Here code for my .module file. It is available here as well: http://pastebin.com/EYFgneie

```
/**
* Implements hook_block_info()
*/
function kcc_menu_block_info() {
    $blocks = array();

    //This IS being called
    dpm('hook_block_info');

    $blocks['kcc_menu_block'] = array(
        'info' => 'KCC Menu', 
        'subject' => 'Menu within a block generated by a module.', 
        'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE, 
        'properties' => array(), 
        'weight' => null, 
        'status' => 1, 
        'visibility' => null, 
        'pages' => null, 
        'region' => 'sidebar', 
        );
    return $blocks;
}

/**
* Implements hook_block_view()
*/
function kcc_menu_block_view($delta = '') {
    $block = array();
    switch($delta) {
        case 'kcc_menu_block' :
            //Only show this block on non-admin pages
            if(!path_is_admin(current_path())) {
                $block['content'] = _kcc_menu_block_view_content();
                $block['title'] = _kcc_menu_block_title(); 
            }
        break;
    }
    return $block;
}

/**
* Implements hook_block_view_content()
*/
function _kcc_menu_block_view_content() {
    $results = _kcc_menu_block_links();
    return array(
        'message' => array(
            '#type' => 'markup', 
            '#markup' => $results['markup'], 
            '#prefix' => '<div class="kcc_block">', 
            '#suffix' => '</div>', 
            ),
        );
}

/**
* Function to return the entire set of 1st-level links in the sidebar menu
*/
function _kcc_menu_sidebar_links() {
    return menu_tree_all_data('menu-menu-sidebar');
}

/**
* Function that returns the submenu for a specific link item out of a list of menu items.
*/
function _kcc_submenu_tree($menu_items, $mlid) {
    /**
    * The link returned is chosen by the mlid passed.
    *  An empty array will be returned if there are no children.
    *  $menu_items is from array returned from menu_tree_all_data()
    *  Sub-items of that array can be passed here
    */
    foreach($menu_items as $branch) {
        if($branch['link']['mlid'] == $mlid) {
            $child_tree = $branch['below'];
            return $child_tree;
        }
    }
}

/*
* Function to return the block title    
*/
function _kcc_menu_block_title() {
    //The value is returned along with the
    //results from _kcc_menu_block_links()
    $result = _kcc_menu_block_links();
    return $result['title_link']['title'];
}

/*
* Function to determine and return the block content
*/
function _kcc_menu_block_links() {

    $returned = array();

    $sidebar_menu_links = _kcc_menu_sidebar_links();

    //An array of link items representing where the 
    //user is currently located in the menu
    $current_trail_links = menu_get_active_trail($sidebar_menu_links); 
    //Remove 'home' link from the current path
    unset($current_trail_links[0]);

    //Last item in the current trail is the current page
    $current_page_link = end($current_trail_links);
    reset($current_trail_links);

    //Get the set of links for the first level menu item
    $second_level_menu_items = _kcc_submenu_tree($sidebar_menu_links, $current_trail_links[1]['mlid']);

    if($current_page_link['depth'] == 1) {

        //1st level menu item with children
        //Display child links for level 1 menu
        $left_menu_items = $second_level_menu_items;
        $title_link = $current_trail_links[1];
    } 
    elseif($current_page_link['depth'] == 2) {

        $third_level_menu_items = _kcc_submenu_tree($second_level_menu_items, $current_page_link['mlid']);
        $has_children = (!empty($third_level_menu_items)) ? true : false;

        if($has_children) {
            //Display child links in menu
            $left_menu_items = $third_level_menu_items;
            $title_link = $current_trail_links[2];
            //dpm('2nd level menu item with children!');
        }
        else {
            //Display sibling links in menu
            $left_menu_items = $second_level_menu_items;
            $title_link = $current_trail_links[1];
            //dpm('2nd level menu item without children!');
        }
    }
    elseif($current_page_link['depth'] == 3) {

        $third_level_menu_items = _kcc_submenu_tree($second_level_menu_items, $current_trail_links[2]['mlid']); 
        $fourth_level_menu_items = _kcc_submenu_tree($third_level_menu_items, $current_trail_links[3]['mlid']);
        $has_children = (!empty($fourth_level_menu_items)) ? true : false;

        //Display child links for level 2 menu
        //whether or not there are children
        if($has_children) {
            //dpm('3rd level menu item with children');
            $left_menu_items = $third_level_menu_items;
            $title_link = $current_trail_links[2];
        }
        else {
            //dpm('3rd level menu item without children');
            $left_menu_items = $third_level_menu_items;
            $title_link = $current_trail_links[2];
        }
    }
    elseif($current_page_link['depth'] == 4) {

        //Display child links for level 3 menu
        //dpm('4th level menu item without children');
        $third_level_menu_items = _kcc_submenu_tree($second_level_menu_items, $current_trail_links[2]['mlid']);
        $fourth_level_menu_items = _kcc_submenu_tree($third_level_menu_items, $current_trail_links[3]['mlid']);
        $left_menu_items = $fourth_level_menu_items;
        $title_link = $current_trail_links[3];
    }
    else {
        $left_menu_items = null;
    }

    $returned['title_link'] = $title_link;
    $returned['markup'] = '<ul>';
    foreach($left_menu_items as $left_menu_item) {
        $returned['markup'] .= "<li><a href=\"/{$left_menu_item['link']['href']}\">{$left_menu_item['link']['title']}</a></li>";
    }
    $returned['markup'] .= '</ul>';

    return $returned;
}
```

I've exhausted all of my knowledge, so I'm up for any and all suggestions. Thanks in advance for you help!

Comment: Has the module name remained consistent? Make sure it matches what you are putting as the prefix before your hooks. That's gotten me a few times. Also, see if commenting out the "Only show this block on non-admin pages" condition makes it show up.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm still having no luck. I don't think it has anything to do with my module, but rather something on the site.  Also, the only function being called is kcc_menu_block_info(), whereas on the other sites they all get called.

Answer (score 1):

I have no clue why, but having this in hook_block_info() is causing my problem:

```
'status' => 1,
```

That is supposed to set the block to be enabled by default, but for some reason it removes the block from /admin/structure/block for all three sites.

This solved my problem, but it doesn't seem right. Any thoughts?